Invalid Input Syntax for Type Integer Error in PostgreSQL
i am working on a project using PostgreSQL, Express.js. The issue occurs when I try to fetch a message by its ID, which results in the following error:
error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "NaN"at C:\Users\KS\OneDrive\Desktop\triyas\odin-message-board\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:45:11at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)at async getMessageByID (file:///C:/Users/KS/OneDrive/Desktop/triyas/odin-message-board/db/queries.js:12:20)at async viewMessage (file:///C:/Users/KS/OneDrive/Desktop/triyas/odin-message-board/controllers/messageController.js:21:19) {length: 146,severity: 'ERROR',code: '22P02',detail: undefined,hint: undefined,position: undefined,internalPosition: undefined,internalQuery: undefined,where: "unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...'",schema: undefined,table: undefined,column: undefined,dataType: undefined,constraint: undefined,file: 'numutils.c',line: '617',routine: 'pg_strtoint32_safe'}

This is my code.
EJS Template:

<% locals.messages.forEach(message => { %>
  <h1><%= message.name %></h1>
  <p><%= message.content %></p>
  <p><%= message.added %></p>
  <a href="/<%= message.id %>"><button>Open</button></a>
<% }); %>

Router:
router.get("/:id", viewMessage);

Controller:
export const viewMessage = async (req, res) => {
  const message = await getMessageByID(req.params.id);
  res.render("message", { message: message });
};

in queries.js:
export const getMessageByID = async (id) => {
  id = parseInt(id);
  console.log(typeof id);  // number

  const { rows } = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM messages where id = $1", [
    id,
  ]);
  console.log(rows);

  return rows;
};

the table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
name text,
content text,
added TIMESTAMP
);


The answer is in the error message "NaN" at ... . You are not passing in a value that can be cast to an integer: select 'NaN'::integer; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "NaN". This will only work with numeric type: select 'NaN'::numeric; NaN. Read Numeric Types for more information.

That should be ... that can not be cast ....

id = parseInt(id) should happen in viewMessage, not in getMessageByID. Also you should log the value and typeof of req.params.id, not of the parsed id.

@Bergi i tried that but got the same error.

@AdrianKlaver   But when i log the type of id (after parsing),  it is a number not NaN

@KrishnaSree So if you logged req.params.id, what value did you see? Please [edit] your question to include that

Believe the error message the issue is with NaN. Take a look a the Postgres  log to see if it can give you more information.
